# How do I check if a field value has changed in a entry_submission_ready hook handler?

Tags: hook

I am writing an extension for the hook

```
entry_submission_ready
```

I see that it has 3 params(meta, data, autosave).

I look at data and I see there is channel data in there and a revision post data index.

I assumed that the revision post data contains the old, not updated data.

But when I compared then to the top level data, they are the same. Both also show the updated data.

Is there any way I can access the old data? Do I need to use a different hook?

How do I know if a field value has been changed by edits?

Comment: 1. isn't revision data only available when revisions are enabled on a channel? 2. To make sure if data is changed by an edit: a) store a copy of the field data at, say, the publish_form_entry_data() hook and check it on entry_submission_ready, or b) check against the database after submit.

Comment: @GDmac good suggestions. Will try some of your solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That hook gives you all the data you need to query the database. `$meta` will hold your `entry_id`, `channel_id`, `title`, etc (anything that goes in `exp_channel_titles`), and `$data` holds your custom field data.

So just as an example:

```
if(!empty($meta['entry_id']))
{
    $current = $this->EE->db->query("
        SELECT * FROM exp_channel_data WHERE entry_id = {$meta['entry_id']} LIMIT 1
    ");
    if($current->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        if($data['field_id_1'] === $current->row('field_id_1'))
        {
            // Data has not changed in field_id_1
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so your solution basically means that I should compare $data with the database values using entry id as the key. I will try if it works.